# How can I use pipe in a variable referrence?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract part of string in a variable as below, but it returned bad substitution.

```
for i in `ls`;do echo ${i|cut -d. -f1};done

-bash: ${i|cut -d. -f1}: bad substitution
```

In my scenario, I wanna rename a batch of files' suffix.
e.g.: change `abc.txt` to `abc.csv`

So, what can I do as the correct syntax?

BTW, I don't know what `${i}` this format is called?

Comment: Can you show expected input and output?

Comment: `for i in `ls`;do echo ${i} | cut -d "." -f1;done` it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to remove everything after the first dot in the names available in the current directory.

To loop over all the names in the current directory, use

```
for name in *; do ...; done
```

Using the output of `ls` for anything other than for visual inspection is error prone and should be avoided. See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

To remove the bit after the first dot in `$name` (including the dot itself), use `${name%%.*}`.  This is a [standard parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) that removes the longest suffix matching the globbing pattern `.*` from the value of the variable `name`.

To output the result of the this expansion, you may use

```
printf '%s\n' "${name%%.*}"
```

See both [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694) and [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803).

Your full script could be written

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for name in *; do
    printf '%s\n' "${name%%.*}"
done
```

Your second question, about what `${i}` is called:  It's a variable expansion (sometimes the terms "parameter expansion" or "variable/parameter substitution" are used). The `${i}` will be expanded to/substituted by the value of the variable `i`.  This could also be written `$i` as the curly braces do not do anything special here.  The only place where you may want to use `${i}` instead of `$i` is where the expansion is part of a string and the very next character is valid in a variable's name, as in `"${i}_stuff"` (`$i_stuff` would try to expand the variable `i_stuff`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${i%%.*}`. It will remove everything after first occurrence of dot including dot.

e.g.

```
i=absdfsfd.b.c.dddd
echo "${i%%.*}"
```

will give output

```
absdfsfd
```

In your case:

```
 for i in *;do echo "${i%%.*}";done
```

Well do not use `for i in ls`. See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/255251)